Proving convergence of solution of a fixed point equation
I encountered a nasty sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty $ defined as the smallest positive fixed point of the fixed point equation $ x_n = f_n(x_n) $, where $f_n$ is given by
$$ f_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \tfrac{n-1}{2}\rfloor} {n-1 \choose 2k} {2k \choose k} \alpha^k x^{2k} (1-x)^{n-1-2k}, $$
where $\alpha \in (0,1/4)$. From plotting a few values, I think this sequence converges to $0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ in a monotonically decreasing fashion. However, I'm unable to prove it. Does someone have an idea how it could be done? (or thinks that my hunch is incorrect?) Thanks so much!

What does this expression represent? It looks like a probability of some event. It may be simpler to get an idea of the answer if we understand the expression's origin.

Is your $x_n$ the least positive fixed point or something else (there seems to be more than one solution to your fixed point problem)

@fedja Yes, I'm looking for the least positive fixed point. I wasn't sure if maybe a fixed point is unique if it exists. I have edited the question accordingly.

Convergence to $0$ is trivial: as you noticed yourself, the coefficient is just ${n-1\choose k,k,n-1-2k}$. Splitting the rest as $(\sqrt\alpha x)^k(\sqrt\alpha x)^k(1-x)^{n-1-2k}$, we can bound $f_n(x)$ by the full trinomial sum
$$
f_n(x)\le\sum_{k+l+m=n-1}{n-1\choose k,l,m}(\sqrt\alpha x)^k(\sqrt\alpha x)^l(1-x)^m=(1-x+2\sqrt\alpha x)^{n-1}\,.
$$
Since your $\alpha<\frac 14$, the RHS is $(1-\beta x)^{n-1}$ with $\beta=1-2\sqrt\alpha>0$, so $f_n(x)$ tends to $0$ uniformly as $n\to\infty$ on every interval $[\delta,1]$ with $\delta>0$.
That also provides a simple but effective bound $x_n=O(\frac{\log n}{n})$ and makes the monotonicity claim quite plausible, but by no means proves it. Do you care about that part, or not really?

Thanks a lot for your answer! But how do we conclude with $x_n \rightarrow 0$ from the fact that $f_n \rightarrow 0$ uniformly? Wouldn't we need to know more about $x_n$? If, for example, $x_n = e^{-n}$, we would have $(1-\beta x_n)^{n-1} \rightarrow 1$ and not 0.

If $f_n(x)$ goes to  uniformly, and $x_n=f_n(x_n)$ is a value of $f_n$, then $x_n$ also goes to 0. Or is less than $\delta$

That makes sense, thanks. If we constrain $x_n$ to be in $[0,1]$, can we then conclude that the solution $x_n = f_n(x_n)$ is unique?

$x_n$ eventually decreases.
Denote $\beta=\sqrt\alpha$, then $0<\beta<1/2$. Then $f_n(0)=1>0$ and therefore $x_n$ is the maximal positive number for which $$f_n(x)=[t^0](\beta(t+t^{-1})x+1-x)^{n-1}\geqslant x, \, \forall x\in [0,x_n].\tag{1}$$
Here $[t^a]F(t)$ denotes a coefficient of $t^a$ in the Laurent polynomial $F$.
So, in order to prove that $x_n\leqslant x_{n-1}$, it suffices to prove that (1) holds with exponent $n-2$ instead $n-1$, that in turns follows from the inequality $$[t^0](\beta(t+t^{-1})x+1-x)^{n-1}\leqslant 
[t^0](\beta(t+t^{-1})x+1-x)^{n-2}\tag{2}
$$
for all $x\in [0,x_n]$. (2) may be proved by applying the formula $$[t^0]A(t)=\frac1{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}A(e^{is})ds$$
for any Laurent polynomial $A(t)$ and in our situation $\beta(e^{is}+e^{-is})x+1-x=1-x(1-2\beta \cos s)\leqslant 1$ and also $1-x(1-2\beta \cos s)\geqslant 0$ provided that $x_n\leqslant 1/(1+2\beta)$, that holds for large enough $n$, as shown by fedja.

Thanks so much for your answer! I'm having trouble understanding your approach. Why can we define $x_n$ as the least positive number for which (1) holds? I'm currently unable to see the connection to $f_n$.

Because this coefficient is $f_n(x)$, and $f_n(0)>0$
